# escaping special characters between HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

Current application i am working on has lots of Javascript. Frequent conversion from javascript object to HTML element happens. Backend is JAVA. Wondering if there is a easier or better way to handle things rather than always escaping between javascript to HTML and vice-versa.

For example: Every input field has javascript validation, for that i need to JS escape  and after validation it populates into different html element.

Comment: Could you add a specific example with code so that we can see an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

In html5 you can validate using:
`<input type=text pattern=[A-Z]>`
In this case is only accepted upper case letters. But older browsers, not compatible with HTML5 you will need the js validation.